# SUMIF Function to sum 2 criteria in the same range

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Right how I have a SUMIF Function that looks like 
SUMIFS(M6:M13, N6:N13, "/M", C6:C13, **SUM("Inforce", "Modify")**
In the last range I want it to sum if the text criteria is either "Inforce" or "Modify" but I can't see to figure out a working syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this array formula:

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(M6:M13, N6:N13, "/M", C6:C13,{"Inforce", "Modify"})
```

Entered as array formula with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

It basically runs two SUMIFS and adds their results.

Comment: what should I do if I want to concatenate something before and after?
So like =concatenate("$", SUM(SUMIFS(M6:M13, N6:N13, "/M", C6:C13,{"Inforce", "Modify"}), " /M"), it ends up putting the {} around my entire formula instead of the sumif part that I want

Comment: Not sure I get your question. @GraceL

Comment: Sorry I pressed enter before finishing my question does it make more sense now?

Comment: It should still work properly. @GraceL.

Comment: It does work perfectly, I must've made some syntax error earlier. Thank you very much!